# How to use comparator using ranges of values?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Let's say I have a class `Person` with attributes `age and name`. I would like to order a list of person using age ranges, and inside that range by name for example. 
These ranges could be of 10 years for example. A more graphic example:

- Person 1: 10 nick
- Person 2: 13 albert
- Person 3: 26 alex
- Person 4: 22 oliver

The comparator should return `person 2 > person 1 > person 3 > person 4`.

I tried about implementing a comparator using `Math.abs(p1.age - p2.age)` but it does not work as expected.

How can I implement a comparator to return a comparator using ranges of the age attribute in this case?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained

Comment: I suspect `Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getAge() / 10).thenComparing(Person::getName, Collator.getInstance())` would work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide the age by 10 - using integer division will just discard the "ones" part and leave you with easy to compare integers. Java 8's comparator syntax makes this quite elegant:

```
List<Person> people = /* initialize the list... */
people.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((Person p) -> p.getAge() / 10)
                      .thenComparing(Person::getName));
```

Comment: Fixed typo, and added missing type, since inference engine can't figure it out when you chain methods. ;-)

Comment: What If I have doubles? For example instead of age some kind of number of cake portions that somene ate. With values like 2.3, 3.6, 3.9. Would it be `Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> p.getPortions() / 10.0)` ?

Comment: @Gerardo Probably not. If you want to compare the actual number (e.g., 3.6 is smaller than 3.9), you don't need to divide by 10. If you want some flooring effect (e.g., treat 3.6 and 3.9 as "3 and something"), you'll have to eplicitly `floor`, or cst to `int` anyway

Comment: @Mureinik sorry for my incompetence but how could I make what you say on ranges of 0,5. For example 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 and 0.5 are the same slot. Then 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1 another one, etc. I don't know which floor effect could work, as if I round it may have side effects.

Comment: @Gerardo this almost looks like rounding, but unfortunately, Java rounds 0.5 up and not down. You could use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead, though: `myList.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble((Person p) -> new BigDecimal(p.getAge()).setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).doubleValue())`

Comment: @Mureinik so there is no possibility to order using slots? Maybe I could use a strategy based on multiply the values by 100 or some kind of value?

Comment: @Gerardo the snippet I provided will sort by such "slots", no worries

Comment: @Mureinik but your snippet would return the same value for 3.6 and 4.4, while they whould be in different ones

Comment: @Gerardo huh! good catch, thanks! multiplying by two and then flooring should work

Comment: @Mureinik why should work this approach?? 3.6 * 2 = 7.2 by flooring we get 7. Maybe I'm missing something